# Mysql database warning

Tags: php, mysql, database

So i creating registration for my page and i got this error after clicking "submit" button...i have created mysql table and i don´t know why is this error showing... 
Error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2013): Lost connection to MySQL
>   server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 95
>   "Operation not supported" in /home/u771616840/public_html/FreeDay/PHP
>   Form 2/configdb.php on line 2

Database Error

Registration code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include('configdb.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 //whether the username is blank
 if($_POST['username'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['username'] = "User Name is required.";
 }
 //whether the email is blank
 if($_POST['email'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "E-mail is required.";
 }
 else
 {
  //whether the email format is correct
  if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email']))
  {
   //if it has the correct format whether the email has already exist
   $email= $_POST['email'];
   $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";
   $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
            {
    $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "This Email is already used.";
   }
  }
  else
  {
   //this error will set if the email format is not correct
   $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "Your email is not valid.";
  }
 }
 //whether the password is blank
 if($_POST['password'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['password'] = "Password is required.";
 }
 //if the error exist, we will go to registration form
 if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
 {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
 }
 else
 {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $com_code = md5(uniqid(rand()));

  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, password, com_code) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$com_code')";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error());

  if($result2)
  {
   $to = $email;
   $subject = "Confirmation from TutsforWeb to $username";
   $header = "TutsforWeb: Confirmation from TutsforWeb";
   $message = "Please click the link below to verify and activate your account. rn";
   $message .= "http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?passkey=$com_code";

   $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

   if($sentmail)
            {
   echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
   }
   else
         {
    echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
   }
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Configdb file:

```
<?php
 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','dbusername','dbpassword','databasename') or die("Database Error");
?>
```

Thanx for help :)

Comment: this doesn't help you `or die("Database Error")` this does `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))`

Comment: Once you have changed the code as per @Fred-ii-. Then try changing `'localhost'` to `'127.0.0.1'`

Comment: Ok guys so i done what you said and now it showing 2 errors ...First- `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111 "Connection refused") in /home/u771616840/public_html/FreeDay/PHP Form 2/configdb.php on line 2` Second: `Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/u771616840/public_html/FreeDay/PHP Form 2/configdb.php on line 2`

Comment: is your mysql daemon running on local

Comment: You should read up on SQL injection, this code is very vulnerable.

Comment: nope..now it works...code is fully working...problem was just because of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

i want to share my solution to this problem...MySQL was showing this error because i had wrong table type...in register.php is following:

```
 $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $com_code = md5(uniqid(rand()));
```

So you must create following to your table...first line of table must be username, second email and then password and com_code. You can't give them other name because you have defined this table names in your php file...
If this won't help then check if you have right data type...for password is **INT** and for text just **TEXT**

Comment: the error you mention above just simply say, I'm unable to connect..      There are many reason for this issue..